# jQuery Mobile + Cordova random errors on startup, stuck on a grey circle in the middle

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a jQuery Mobila app wrapped with Cordova that I test on my Android device. It is fine when I launch it normally, but when I use a web intent (https://github.com/Initsogar/cordova-webintent) to launch it, the console debug shows random errors coming from the jQuery Mobile js file:

> D/CordovaLog(24140): file:///android_asset/www/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js: Line 7661 : Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'addClass'
>
> D/CordovaLog(22727): file:///android_asset/www/jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js: Line 10116 : Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'each'

I am aware that these bugs are properly caused by the code I am trying to render on startup, and I'm guessing that the js files I include in the  tags in index.html might be in the wrong order. Here is my current setup:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>       
    <script src="jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>         
    <script src="jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js"></script>      
    <script src="js/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jstorage.js"></script>  
    <script src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>        
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
```

I have also tried putting jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js under jquery-1.9.1.min.js, but similar things have happened.

Afterwards, I re-ordered them into this:

```
    <script src="jquery/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>        
    <script src="jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery/jquery.mjs.nestedSortable.js"></script>      
    <script src="js/json2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jstorage.js"></script>  
     
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>       
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
```

And it seemed to work fine for a while or so, but am still seeing jQuery Mobile bugs here and there.

Comment: Do you execute functions from your script only after "deviceready" event? If not, you should rewrite code so that everything is executed only after this event.

Comment: Have you tried to load your js in a IDE with good syntax checking (like netbeans with html5 project)? I suspect some syntax error in index.js. What errors do you now have in the logs?

Comment: This problem only arises from using it on my phone due to detectimg the deviceReady event, while developing and testing in the Chrome console is totally fine. Will update more later.

Comment: Have you resolved this? I am experiencing a similar issue.